# Unable to stop SQL injection errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-injection

I finally get it. It's not just the code I use to execute the ExecuteScalar method but it is mainly the code up stream that is executing the class.  It is everything calling your code. That said, can someone please see if the code executing the my SQL class has faults. I still cant pass the scans. First I will show you two examples of the code calling my code, then the calling code, and finally the executing code, which I formulated and displayed from a previous post.

**Calling code with three parameters:**

```
public bool isTamAsp(int aspKey, int fy, string accountCode)
{
    MyParam myParam;

    string sqlQuery = "select isTamMacom = count(macom_key) FROM hier_fy " +
        "WHERE hier_key = @aspKey AND fy = @fy  AND @accountCode NOT IN (3,4,7,8) AND macom_key IN (select hier_key from lkup_e581_MacomThatRequireTAM) AND is_visible = 1 AND is_active = 1";

    QueryContainer Instance = new QueryContainer(sqlQuery);

    myParam = new MyParam();

    myParam.SqlParam = new SqlParameter("@aspKey", Instance.AddParameterType(_DbTypes.Int));

    myParam.SqlParam.Value = aspKey;

    Instance.parameterList.Add(myParam);

    myParam = new MyParam();

    myParam.SqlParam = new SqlParameter("@fy", Instance.AddParameterType(_DbTypes.Int));

    myParam.SqlParam.Value = fy;

    Instance.parameterList.Add(myParam);

    myParam = new MyParam();

    myParam.SqlParam = new SqlParameter("@accountCode", Instance.AddParameterType(_DbTypes._string));

    myParam.SqlParam.Value = accountCode;

    Instance.parameterList.Add(myParam);

    if (Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScaler(Instance)) < 1)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Calling code with no parameters:**

```
public long GetMarinesUploadNextUploadKey()
{
    string query = "SELECT MAX(upload_key) FROM temp_auth_usmc_upload";

    QueryContainer Instance = new QueryContainer(query);

    string result = Convert.ToString(ExecuteScaler(Instance));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        return 1;
    else
        return Convert.ToInt64(result) + 1;
}
```

**Code calling my previous code with three parameters:**

```
public bool isTamAsp(int aspKey, int fy, string accountCode)
{
    return e581provider.isTamAsp(aspKey, fy, accountCode);
}
```

**Method calling the SQL executing my code:**

```
DbCommand command = _provider.CreateCommand();

command.Connection = _connection;
{
    command.CommandText = Instance.Query;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    if (Instance.parameterList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var p in Instance.parameterList)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(p.SqlParam);
        }
    }

    if (_useTransaction) { command.Transaction = _transaction; }

    try
    {
        returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

My Class containing the SQL string and the cmd parameter List

```
public enum _DbTypes
{
    Int = 1, _string = 2, _long = 3, _bool = 4, _DateTime = 5,
    _decimal = 6, _float = 7, _short = 8, _bite = 9
} 

public class MyParam
{
    public SqlParameter SqlParam { get; set; }
}
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for QueryContainer SGH
/// </summary>
public class QueryContainer
{

    string _query;

    public List<MyParam> parameterList = new List<MyParam>();

    public QueryContainer(string query) { _query = query; }

    public SqlDbType AddParameterType(_DbTypes id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case _DbTypes.Int:
                return (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), "int", true);
            case _DbTypes._string:
                return (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), "NVarChar", true);
            case _DbTypes._long:
                return (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), "SqlDbType.BigInt", true);
            case _DbTypes._bool:
                return (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), "SqlDbType.Bit", true);
        }

        return SqlDbType.VarChar;

    }

    public string Query
    {
        get
        {
            return _query;
        }

        set { _query = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `, _bite = 9`  nom nom nom

Comment: I don't get this. The code you have here is **not** vulnerable to sql injection attacks. The worst thing I see is a race condition on the `GetMarinesUploadNextUploadKey()` method (you should use an identity column or sequence there instead). The code also goes through a _lot_ of needless work to produce it's own wrappers for the existing types, and all that you get for that work is something more complicated than what you already had.

Comment: What is calling the first method? Is it possible for the "accountCode" to contain a SQL Injection attack? It gets plopped right into a string that is eventually executed; perhaps that's why you're getting a vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a vulnerability in that code, but I have an idea what the scan may be asking for. The problem could be that this code makes it too easy for developers to ignore the `parameterList` collection in your class. If I'm a new developer in your organization who hasn't discovered Sql injection yet, I'd be tempted to ignore all that complicated query parameter stuff and just use string concatenation before setting your `Query` property.

Instead of wrapping this in a class, what I'm more used to seeing is a single method that has a signature like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string query, IEnumerable<Sqlparameter> parameters)
```

...or some permutation of that method signature that may use arrays or lists instead of `IEnumerable`. This forces downstream developers to deal with that `parameters` argument to the method. They can't ignore it, and so the temptation to use a quick, lazy string concatenation call to substitute some user-provided data into the query is reduced.

Comment: One of the concerns that I have is that if the query string has no parameters could that show up as a finding?